# Rule about a username for SoftLayer Customer Portal

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Would you tell me the rule about a username for SoftLayer Customer Portal.
I found the rules about a password but could not find the rules about a username.

```
Portal passwords must...
* ...be over eight characters long.
* ...be under twenty characters long.
* ...contain at least one uppercase letter
* ...contain at least one lowercase letter
* ...contain at least one number
* ...contain one of the special characters _ - | @ . , ? / ! ~ # $ % ^ & * ( ) { } [ ] \ + =
* ...not match your username
* ...not match your forum password
```

http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_User_Customer_OpenIdConnect/processPasswordSetRequest

I will not use APIs though this link is from Documentation of APIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There’s no similar method like **processPasswordSetRequest** in the API for the username attribute.

Nevertheless, the next are the restrictions for setting up the username:

- The username cannot be a duplicate of another user in the account. Usernames are separated by account to avoid conflicts with standard users.
- Only ASCII characters are supported.
- Username can’t be empty
- Username should not be larger than 100 characters.